# give out an award

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is from [a webpage](https://www.oyf.com/distributed-work/tool-award-show):

> The recipient gives a mini acceptance speech, and then they become the next person to **give out an award**.

What does 'give out something' mean here. Does it mean 'to give something to a lot of people' or 'to tell people about something or broadcast something'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give out means the same thing as give in your sentence.

What your expression implies is that the recipient first receives the award, and following that, gives (or hands) the award to the next person (next recipient).

Answer (score 0):

Some synonyms could be "to present" and award or "to hand out."  In the context of your question, the person who wins the award presents it to the next winner at the next award ceremony.

Comment: Thank you very much.